# Highchart always show max value for y Axis

Tags: highcharts

I set the max value for yAxis [but in some situation](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadgaj/fbbGY/3072/), I see a value more than `max` value that I set for Highchart.

I need in any situation `max` value will be shown in yAxis.

Answer (score 1):

By default Highcharts computes values for ticks and may round up the maximum extreme so that it has the same value as the last tick.

You can modify ticks in `tickPositioner` callback to make sure that the max value will always be shown as a tick:

```
  yAxis: {
    max: 110,
    min: -20,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      var tickPositions = this.tickPositions,
        lastTick = tickPositions[tickPositions.length - 1],
        max = this.options.max;

      if (lastTick > max) {
        tickPositions.pop(); // remove last tick
        tickPositions.push(max);
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8k4skeh9/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 0):

With `tickInterval` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval)) it's works

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/fbbGY/3073/)

Edit :
For dynamic data you can use `SetExtreme method` [API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis%23setExtremes#setExtremes) or `update` to update the `tickInterval`  [API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis%23setExtremes#update)

Comment: Since I have a lot of dynamic data, it's not a good solution because if you set `tickInterval` value to `20` you can see it doesn't work as well.